# Understanding basic concept regarding multi-threading

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

**Question:** 
What is the advantage and/or possible disadvantages of scheduling all threads of a process together on multiple processors at a time versus scheduling threads (from different processes) one at a time as individual processors become available?

**Update Note:** Consider a multiprocessor and a process with two threads. Suppose only one thread runs at a time. The thread curretly running sends a message to the second thread and then blocks waiting for a reply (and hence is taken off the CPU). After some time, the second thread gets scheduled, receives the message from the first thread, sends the reply and then blocks waiting for new message from the first thread. After some time, the first thread gets scheduled, processes the reply, sends new message and then gets blocked waiting for the new reply and so on. All this switching can be avoided if both threads were running concurrently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, scheduling threads as processors become available and letting them run to completion before scheduling another thread on that processor will generally be more efficient in terms of total throughput because you won't have the overhead of context switching.  However, this assumes that the processes/threads are behaving themselves - in contrast, if a thread goes into an infinite loop or becomes deadlocked then you've permanently lost access to its processor.  Scheduling everything to run all at once introduces context switching overhead, but if a thread/processor isn't well behaved then you can still rely on the operating system to interrupt it occasionally and let another thread/process do some work on that processor.

Answer (score 1):

In general, scheduling all threads of a process together on multiple processors at a time wastes processors.  What do you do if, say, an 8-core processor has two cores running 2 threads in process X and another process Y has seven threads become ready?  Refuse to run Y at all?

The set of ready threads changes as hardware interrupts occur and the running threads make system calls.  It is an unreasonable restraint to force the scheduling algorithm to adopt an 'all ready threads in a process or none' policy.